# Search Server Express install on SP 2007 - Property Relevance

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007

A vendor has installed SSE on SP 2007. I want to adjust the individual property rank weighting/rank parameters so that the weight setting for the property - *body text of a document* - is low (low relevance) and the properties *title and description* are high (high relevance).

The vendor has said that making these config changes are programing changes so I will need to pay more. I also asked for the relevance weights as they come "out of the box" and was told no one knows these as they are part of a secret algorithm - so i'm now in the situation where I have no idea how different properties are influencing search results or I can pay more to have relevance weights I want programmed in.

Are the property relevance weights of an "out-of-the-box" installation of SSE known to anyone?

Is it an unreasonable expectation to an "out of the box" configured as I want and is it that hard to do this?

I just want to have reasonable expectations so would appreciate any advice.

Comment: I've deleted the `sse` tag since this is already used on Stack Overflow for Intel's *Streaming SIMD Extensions*.